# GPG: cannot import private/secret key

Tags: encryption, cryptography, gnupg

I have a public/private GPG keypair. When I try to `gpg --import` either the public or the private key, only the public keyring is updated:

```
[root@ip-10-24-5-35 ~]# gpg --list-keys
/root/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
------------------------
pub   4096R/A6E928B1 2018-07-02
uid                  saids_ftp (some description) <said@example.com>
sub   4096R/5010A53E 2018-07-02

[root@ip-10-24-5-35 ~]# gpg --list-secret-keys
[root@ip-10-24-5-35 ~]#
```

Later, when I try to decrypt a file, I get the following output:

```
[root@ip-10-24-5-35 raw]# gpg --decrypt file.txt.gpg
gpg: encrypted with RSA key, ID FFAB8C83
gpg: encrypted with RSA key, ID D66EFA2A
gpg: encrypted with RSA key, ID 2FA063D3
gpg: encrypted with RSA key, ID 038D4A79
gpg: encrypted with ELG key, ID D5D81FBC
gpg: encrypted with RSA key, ID 45ED8372
gpg: encrypted with RSA key, ID CC1446EE
gpg: encrypted with 4096-bit RSA key, ID 5010A53E, created 2018-07-02
      "saids_ftp (some description) <said@example.com>"
gpg: encrypted with RSA key, ID 75BB9DFE
gpg: encrypted with RSA key, ID B2ECF5E4
gpg: encrypted with ELG key, ID 2AD775F8
gpg: encrypted with RSA key, ID B5F82E2E
gpg: encrypted with RSA key, ID D8098B00
`enter code here`gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

Is there something wrong with my private key? I'm not sure how I exported it in the past, as the server that the key was created on is no longer available.

Comment: Some resources ([eg](http://irtfweb.ifa.hawaii.edu/~lockhart/gpg/)) state you need to use `--allow-secret-key-import` even though it's marked obsolete. But worth a try I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure if [this](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html#nosecring) is relevant, but have a quick read.